# Error(s) parsing SQL: Unexpected token near *!*

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
Error(s) parsing SQL:
Unexpected token near *!* in the following:
SELECT RESOURCEID AS RESOURCEID, MAX(ROWKEY) ROWKEY, MIN(PRODUCTIONDATE) PRODUCTIONDATE, CAST(SUM(UNITS) AS *!*NUMERIC (9)) UNITS, MAX(BUCKETSTART) BUCKETSTART FROM(
Unexpected token near *!* in the following:
SELECT RESOURCEID AS RESOURCEID, MAX(ROWKEY) ROWKEY, MIN(PRODUCTIONDATE) PRODUCTIONDATE, CAST(SUM(UNITS) AS NUMERIC *!*(9)) UNITS, MAX(BUCKETSTART) BUCKETSTART FROM(
Expecting identifier near *!* in the following:
SELECT RESOURCEID AS RESOURCEID, MAX(ROWKEY) ROWKEY, MIN(PRODUCTIONDATE) PRODUCTIONDATE, CAST(SUM(UNITS) AS NUMERIC (*!*9)) UNITS, MAX(BUCKETSTART) BUCKETSTART FROM(
```

This the error which i get when i try to create the view...but it runs successfully as a select statement.

Below is the Code:

```
SELECT RESOURCEID, MAX(ROWKEY) ROWKEY, MIN(PRODUCTIONDATE) PRODUCTIONDATE, CAST(SUM(UNITS) AS NUMERIC(9)) UNITS, MAX(BUCKETSTART) BUCKETSTART FROM(
    SELECT RESOURCEID, ROWKEY, PRODUCTIONDATE, UNITS, BUCKETSTART , SUM(BUCKETSTART)
        OVER(PARTITION BY RESOURCEID ORDER BY RESOURCEID,PRODUCTIONDATE) BUCKET FROM(
        SELECT RESOURCEID, MAX(PRODUCTIONDAY.ROWKEY) ROWKEY, PRODUCTIONDAY.PRODUCTIONDATE, CAST(SUM(PRODUCTIONDAY.UNITS) AS NUMERIC(9)) UNITS,
            MAX(PRODUCTIONDAY.BUCKETSTART) BUCKETSTART FROM m1si_wsl.PRODUCTIONDAY GROUP BY PRODUCTIONDAY.PRODUCTIONDATE, RESOURCEID)
)GROUP BY BUCKET, RESOURCEID
```

Comment: Remove the "*!*" part from CAST(SUM(UNITS) AS *!*NUMERIC (9)).

Comment: What version of SQL Developer are you using, and do you get this creating a view using a query that runs fine on its own, just as a select? Showing the statement you're executing would help, possibly with the table DDL; or even better minimise it to the smallest code that can get this error. This sounds like a bug in a really old version though, so perhaps upgrade to version 4 and see if you still see the problem.

Comment: Alex..thanks for replying.. yes the code runs successfully as a select statement..but when i try to compile it to create the view..it throws this particular error

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer Release 3.0 (3.0.04.34) is what I am using..but it works flawlessly for everything else...my best guess is that there is some error with the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this using the SQL Developer 'new view' dialog box:

[image: SQL Developer view dialog]

It isn't a problem when run as a script from an SQL Worksheet:

```
select CAST(SUM(1) AS NUMERIC (9)) units from dual;

UNITS                  
---------------------- 
1                      

create view v42 as
select CAST(SUM(1) AS NUMERIC (9)) units from dual;

view V42 created.
```

This seems to be a parser bug that's specific to the dialog box, with it not handling the ANSI `NUMERIC` type; it's fine if you use the [equivalent](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/sql_elements001.htm#i54335) Oracle `NUMBER` type instead:

[image]

I got the syntax error in the version you are using, 3.0.04, and also in 3.1.07 and 3.2.20; but not in 4.0.0 so it seem to have been fixed in that major release. As a further check, in the current early-adopter version 4.1.0.17 it is OK with your original statement:

[image]

So your choices seem to be to use normal Oracle data types, or if you're set on using ANSI types, either create the view from a worksheet or upgrade to the current version of SQL Developer.